PDF Form Required Dropdown Issues
Can anyone help I have a PDF form which has a mix of text fields and dropdown selections.
I am having problems with required dropdowns : example: name of the dropdown "Currency" (first entry being the default a space and 3 other options)

" "
"GBP"
"EUR"
"USD

Another required dropdown is names "Status"

" "
"New"
"Old"
"In Situ"

Even though I have marked the dropdown fields as required fields the form will still allow you to click on a submit button (mailto: ) at the end of the form and email it to someone if the Currency field and the status field is left on the default option.
Where as I would like a message to appear if they have not selected GBP / USD or EUR such as "Missing Currency" and In the other dropdown if they have not selected New / Old or In Situ then the message "Missing Status

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What software are you using to create this?

Yes, the application they are using is going to be information basic to the question, something we really need to know in order to help them.

You will need to detect if either field is null or if both are selected


However to run such scripts is very much down to working with and using Adobe JS security.
For the above mock-up I have coded the button but that will not be how you set in your editor.
7 0 obj
<</A<</JS(
// loop through required fields in the document\r\nvar dd1 = this.getField\("Dropdown1"\).valueAsString;\r\nvar dd2 = this.getField\("Dropdown2"\).valueAsString;\r\n/*establish if condition, is the field value empty */\r\nif \(dd1 == " " || dd2 == " "\){\r\napp.alert \("You did not save with both a Currency and a Status selected"\);\r\n}\r\nelse app.alert \(dd1 + " " + dd2\);)
/S/JavaScript>>/AP<</N 13 0 R>>/BS<</S/B>>/DA(0 g /Helv 12 Tf)/F 4/Ff 65536/FT/Btn/MK<</BC[0 0 0]/BG[.752941 .752941 .752941]/CA(Button)>>/P 9 0 R/Rect[150.32212 676.5608 222.32212 696.5608]/Subtype/Widget/T(Button1)/Type/Annot>>
endobj

